# Why are both of these Drobo daemons running?

Tags: mac, drobo, droboshare

I have a DroboShare and Drobo dashboard running on my 64-bit Mac, and for some reason I have two different Drobo support daemons running:

```
com.datarobotics.ddserviced
"/Library/Application Support/Data Robotics/Drobo Dashboard/DDServiced"
```

and

```
com.datarobotics.ddservice64d
"/Library/Application Support/Data Robotics/Drobo Dashboard/DDService64d"
```

It seems to me that one of these is probably redundant, but they're both enabled. Could I safely disable one of these?

Answer (score 2):

When I upgraded my 64-bit iMac from Snow Leopard to Lion, Drobo Dashboard stopped launching.  It complained "a required portion of drobo dashboard is no longer running."  Un-installing and re-installing the latest Dashboard did not solve the problem.  What *did* solve the problem was opening a Terminal window, navigating to /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library/Application\ Support/Data\ Robotics/ and launching DDServiced and DDService64d.  When I launched DDServiced, a message appeared saying the service was already running, followed by a crash report.  When I launched DDService64d, a ports-permissions dialog appeared, to which I consented, and then Dashboard opened.

So, based on my experience, when the 64d service is not running, Drobo Dashboard won't start.  Don't disable that one.